# Error No pages of output. Transcript written on grid.log

Tags: errors, compiling

Maybe this is an off topic or just seen before and closed but two days ago I had to reinstall the yosemite os and reinstall TeXShop and all the necessary files to work on latex. The problem is that all for all the files I have, at the time of compile them, I got the following error (never happened before and as I said, they worked perfectly before the OS re-install):

```
AED: lastpage setting LastPage
(./grid.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on grid.log.
```

I have installed also Ghostscript and a bunch of additional apps, apparently to solve the problem, but it continues. I have also checked the preferences and seems to be fine, I mean, distiller is /usr/local/bin and /Library/TeX/texbin

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ghostscript doesn't appear to be involved at all but it's impossible to help given the information posted so far. All you show is the end of the console output from an error free tex run with no output, eg  a tex file  that just said `\bye` would produce that.

Comment: I know but it is from a file that worked perfectly few days ago, for that reason it doesn't make sense to post the whole code (it is quite long and bothering). Now it seems that something is missed when I re-installed everything but I am incapable to figure out what it is. I am quite puzzled. Thanks anyway :(

Comment: delete grid.aux grid.log (and any grid.toc grid.lof etc that might exist) add \tracingall to grid.tex then re-run latex. If tex is running at all you should have a very verbose log that will pinpoint the error exactly

Comment: Impossible to decode the log given the amount of data listed. It lasts almost one minute. Almost giving it up. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No that's good that is already information (Tex is running on the existing file you edited not some stale copy in the input path somewhere) , so you can move `\tracingall` later in the file (eg just before `\end{document}` and get a trace just of the error area, or if that does not cause a log then tex isn't reaching there so move \tracingall back until you find where the error is.

Comment: Error found but not with "\tracingall", just doing manually and checking each single package, seemed to be the package: "\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}". Thanks anyway :)